# AND and OR operators, regex and value length

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I'm trying to get it to prevent the entering of anything non numeric and input value length no greater than 6. Right now it works by blocking anything more than 6 characters, if the input contains alpha. But when I change it to block if it's alpha OR greater than 6 characters I can't enter anything at all. Any thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/;
        $('#input1,#input2').keypress(function (e) {
            var length = this.value.length;
            if (!pattern.test($(this).val()) && (length >= 6)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the way you crafted your regex, the first letter pressed won't be shown in the `$(this).val()` until after the end of that function (it's why you're still able to use `e.preventDefault();`); this means that the val the regex is testing is blank which the regex won't match.

I'd recommend you append the next character onto the current value, that way you can test against what the string *will be*, not what it is.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/;
  $('#input1,#input2').keypress(function (e) {
    var curVal = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    var length = curVal.length;

    if (length > 6 || !pattern.test(curVal)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }); 
});
```

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/mazzzzz/pen/oatDq).  The codepen does a few things different, because there are better ways to do this then using a costly regex (which doesn't matter all the time, but I like to optimize).

Answer (score 3):

Complementing what mazzzzz said, you can test what you want with a more powerfull pattern:

```
var pattern = /^\d{1,6}$/;
```

This will only accept digits (\d) with 1 to 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't need regular expressions here at all.

```
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxLen = 6,
        helpCodes = [37, 39, 8, 9], // left and right arrows, backspace, tab
        codes = [];
    for(var code = 48; code < 58; code++) { // number keys (48-57)
        codes.push(code);
    }
    $('#input1,#input2').on('keydown', function (e) {
        if(helpCodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if(e.shiftKey || this.value.length == maxLen
                || codes.indexOf(e.keyCode) < 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/9mpde/)